# Creating an account fails with "Failed to get account from validator, error: Waypoint value mismatch"

Tags: cryptocurrency, diem, move-lang

## the use case

I am following the tutorial to create my first transaction: https://developers.diem.com/docs/tutorials/my-first-transaction

I run `Ubuntu 20.04`

I executed those commands successfully:

```
git clone https://github.com/diem/diem.git && cd diem
git checkout testnet
./scripts/dev_setup.sh
```

## The error:

I created a first account with this command

```
libra% account create
```

The creation of the command triggered this error:

```
>> Creating/retrieving next local account from wallet
2020-12-18T21:02:29.644049Z [main] ERROR testsuite/cli/src/client_proxy.rs:1320 

Failed to get account from validator, error: Waypoint value mismatch: 
waypoint value = 3139c30efe6dbde4228efb9df32c137dc3a2490b97ab6a086897be1d0cb336f0
, given value = 8ce65af8ca7ad5c9da796fbfccdc1bd53f5cdf58616322d5d574c7ca93ddd583

Created/retrieved local account #0 address bda28b9df5b779a854f6f0a035d10484
```

1. How can I know where does the waypoint 8ce65a comes from? I have found where the 3139c3 waypoint came from: https://testnet.libra.org/waypoint.txt
2. I see the final message stating that the account was created though. Is it a safe assumption?

Answer (score 0):

The waypoints are generated on Diem at regular intervals, say epoch boundaries.

Initially the account might not appear on the ledger as it is not synced. The account would appear after the sync has happened, it is safe